# See Enumerated Indices of Array in Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In short, I have arrays that are referenced by index from an enumeration. In the inspector window of Unity, however, it simply shows "Element 0, Element 1, etc". I want the list to show the index values of my enumeration. Unless a new feature was added to Unity, I suppose this requires a special editor script, but it seems like game code can't even interface with editor code. So how do I go about this? Thanks in advance!

So if I have this:

```c#
public enum ObjectList
{
    Car,
    Sword,
    Friends,
    Depression,
    NumObjects
}

[Somehow declare to use my ObjectList Enum]
public bool [] hasItem = new bool[(int)ObjectList.NumObjects];
```

Ideally, the inspector would now show:

```
Has Item
    Size        4
    Car         []
    Sword       []
    Friends     []
    Depression  []
```

Instead of:

```
Has Item
    Size        4
    Element 0   []
    Element 1   []
    Element 2   []
    Element 3   []
```

Edit: Additional Example as Int Array (not just bool)

```
Num Item
    Size        4
    Car         0
    Sword       10
    Friends     0
    Depression  50
```

Comment: A similar question was asked at https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-the-name-of-list-elements-in-the-inspector.448910/. You will need to build a custom inspector, [here is a good tutorial from Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/building-custom-inspector)

Comment: Side note, for your array size, you should useEnum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Length;, using the last item of the enum is a bit of a hack and considering it is not meant to be an element of the array...well you get the idea.

Comment: @Everts I guess that is what I was looking for previously but was shocked not to find a simple enum.length. It looks like it might be a bit of extra overhead that way though having to create an entire array of string names just to ask it its length. Unless the array already exists anyway?

Comment: it actually creates a new array when you call but this is one time so I would not really bother about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly how you describe it but something very similar already exists:

[Enum Flags](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/EnumFlagPropertyDrawer)

---

I rewrote the scripts a bit:

Place this script anywhere in `Assets` e.g. like `Assets/Plugins/EnumFlag`

**EnumFlagAttribute.cs**

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class EnumFlagAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    public enum FlagLayout
    {
        Dropdown,
        List
    }

    public FlagLayout _layout = FlagLayout.Dropdown;

    public EnumFlagAttribute() { }

    public EnumFlagAttribute(FlagLayout layout)
    {
        _layout = layout;
    }
}
```

And copy this editor script in a folder called `Editor` (doesn't matter where it is placed in the `Assets` only it's name counts) so e.g. `Assets/Plugins/EnumFlag/Editor` → Unity automatically excludes all scripts placed in folders called `Editor` from the final build so there will be no build errors due to the `UnityEditor` namespace.

**EnumFlagDrawer.cs**

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EnumFlagAttribute))]
public class EnumFlagDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Enum)
        {
            switch (((EnumFlagAttribute)attribute)._layout)
            {
                case EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout.Dropdown:
                    property.intValue = EditorGUI.MaskField(position, label, property.intValue, property.enumNames);
                    break;

                case EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout.List:
                    var buttonsIntValue = 0;
                    var enumLength = property.enumNames.Length;
                    var flagSet = new bool[enumLength];

                    EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), label);
                    EditorGUI.indentLevel++;


                    var posX = position.x;
                    EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < enumLength; i++)
                        {
                            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                            // Check if the flag is currently set
                            if (((EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout)property.intValue).HasFlag((EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout)(1 << i)))
                            {
                                flagSet[i] = true;
                            }

                            EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(new Rect(posX, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), new GUIContent(property.enumNames[i]));

                            var toogePosition = new Rect(posX + EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight);
                            flagSet[i] = GUI.Toggle(toogePosition, flagSet[i], property.enumNames[i]);


                            if (flagSet[i])
                            {
                                buttonsIntValue += 1 << i;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                    {
                        property.intValue = buttonsIntValue;
                    }


                    EditorGUI.indentLevel--;

                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var color = GUI.color;
            GUI.color = new Color(1f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
            EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, position.height), label);
            position.x += EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth;
            EditorGUI.HelpBox(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width - EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, position.height), "Use [EnumFlags] only with an enum!", MessageType.Error);
            GUI.color = color;
        }

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (((EnumFlagAttribute)attribute)._layout == EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout.Dropdown)
        {
            return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
        }


        return (property.enumNames.Length + 1) * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }
}
```

---

Then in your code you would use it like

```c#
[System.Flags]
public enum ObjectList
{
    Car = 1 << 0,
    Sword = 1 << 1,
    Friends = 1 << 2,
    Depression = 1 << 3 
}

[EnumFlag]
public ObjectList hasItem;
```

This adds an enum field to your Inspector instead where you can (un)check multiple values instead of only one.

*Note that a lot of tutorials on this manually add a `None` and `All` values to the enum but this is unneccesary as the Unity Inspector adds them automatically.*

[image]

or you can use the List layout I just added to fit to what you wanted to display

```c#
[EnumFlag(EnumFlagAttribute.FlagLayout.List)]
public ObjectList hasItem;
```

This adds the enum field as a list of toggles with according labels instead

[image]

---

**Setting and reading those bitwise flags in a script works a bit different than a usual enum or bool list:**

Setting multiple values using the bitwise OR `|` operator:

```c#
hasItem = ObjectList.Car | ObjectList.Sword;

// or to add a value later
hasItem |= ObjectList.Friends;
```

To remove a certain flag using the bitwise NOT `~` and AND `&` operators

```c#
hasItem &= ~ObjectList.Car;
```

And toggle (invert) a certain flag using the bitwise XOR `^` operator:

```c#
hasItem ^= ObjectList.Car;
```

than to check if certain flags are set using [`HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag)

```c#
bool hasCar = hasItem.HasFlag(ObjectList.Car);
bool hasCarOrSword = hasItem.HasFlag(ObjectList.Car | ObjectList.Sword);
bool hasCarAndSword = hasItem.HasFlag(ObjectList.Car & ObjectList.Sword);
```

---

**UPDATE**

As you added now you would actually rather want to have an `int[]`. This is quite complex as an Attribute with PropertyDrawer since afaik the propertydrawer is than used on every element in that list/array not on the entire list!

You can however instead wrap the list in a class and make a PropertyDrawer for that instead:

**EnumIntArray.cs**

```c#
using System;

[Serializable]
public class EnumIntArray
{
    public string[] Names;
    public int[] Values;

    public EnumIntArray(Type enumType)
    {
        Names = Enum.GetNames(enumType);
        Values = new int[Names.Length];
    }
}
```

**EnumIntArrayDrawer.cs**

```c#
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(EnumIntArray), false)]
public class EnumIntArrayDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), label);

        var values = property.FindPropertyRelative("Values");
        var names = property.FindPropertyRelative("Names");

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

        for (var i = 0; i < values.arraySize; i++)
        {
            var name = names.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
            var value = values.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);

            position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

            var indentedRect = EditorGUI.IndentedRect(position);

            EditorGUI.LabelField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
            value.intValue = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(position.x + EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth - indentedRect.x / 2, position.y, EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth - indentedRect.x, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), value.intValue);
        }

        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }


    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var values = property.FindPropertyRelative("Values");

        return (values.arraySize + 1) * EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }
}
```

and then in your script use it like e.g.

```c#
public EnumIntArray hasItems = new EnumIntArray(typeof(ObjectList));
```

[image]

and for accessing the values

```c#
var carAmount = hasItems.Values[(int)ObjectList.Car];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I didn't realize I'd have to be changing my enumeration to a BitMask to achieve it. The problem with this is that I also have other arrays such as an int array that I had hoped to use the same solution for. Any way to do this for an int [] numItems?

Comment: not that easily actually at least not as attribute... see my update

Comment: This appears to be as close as I can get to what I want. Was hoping to not have to change my data types, but I'll give it a shot! Thanks!